# ERPNEXT installation ERROR "Procfile Does not Exist"

Tags: digital-ocean

I am trying to install ERPNEXT on my machine. When I give this command in shell:

```
bench start
```

It shows me this error:

> [14985][ERROR] Procfile does not exist or is not a file

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
cd ~/frappe-bench
bench start
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.